# Re-apply JQuery in Meteor template

Tags: javascript, jquery, templates, meteor, meteor-blaze

I have a template with a slick carousel, depending on some JQuery. I add this code to the template as follows:

```
Template.show_house.rendered = function () {
    $('#carousel').slick({
      dots: true,
      arrows: true
    });
  };
```

This template depends on a helper:

```
Template.show_house.helpers({
    house : function() {
      return Houses.findOne({_id : Session.get("selectedHouse")});
    },
    ...
```

When the session changes (user clicking on another item), the data in the template changes, but the JQuery isn't applied again, and the images are just shown as a list rather than a carousel.

I've been playing around with UI.render, but to no avail. What can I do?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, the things for is that i wasnt applying the event Template.foo.rendered to the specific template. Try to apply the jquery event on "rendered" to the proper template and see if it works!